# Excel formula not updating for 1 column (works in the rest)

Tags: excel, refresh, formula

I was not able to find the solution anywhere so maybe someone would be able to think of something.
I have a spreadsheet where one of the tabs is build from the cell values from another ones. This is built with blunt =`Paste!AB2`. Everything is refreshing properly **apart from 1 column.**
It keeps on displaying the formula sytnax rather than value. All settings in Excel are set up for automatic updates. I sent the spreadsheet to my friend and it had exactly the same problem. I really dont understand why.

Any ideas?

I cant add a screenshot as I lack reputation :)

Comment: It shouldn't display the formula, even if the formula is wrong. Ensure that the cell doesn't have a space at the beginning (or invisible character code) and it does start with a =. Also try toggling formulas with CTRL ` and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope. There are no spaces. I also tried shortcuts for manual refreshing but this particular one is not updating. Keeps on showing the syntax...

Comment: Do a clear all on the column to remove any weird formatting - and then redo the formulas.

Answer (score 2):

Check the cell types. (Format Cells -> Number Tab) They are probably set to Text.

If so, change the types to General, then **re-enter the formula**

Comment: No. Formulas work if i scroll down and leave current working area. I have to enter the formula in the bottom of the whole worksheet and then copy it up. If I enter it in the used work area  i get the syntax only. This is getting weirder and weirder!